# Combination Connected data access with classes and dataGrid in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

Until now i used the Forms DataGrid bound with disconnected data access (a DataSet). For a new project i should use Connected Data Access, read the tables in Collections of Classes that mirror the structure of the tables (I have no experience with ORM) and then use a WindowsForm Datagrid as UI for working with the collections.

Most of the examples on the web use a DataSet to bind to a DataGrid, does somewone has a simple example of doing the above ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article from MSDN : 
[How to: Bind Objects to Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0wfd4yz.aspx)

Windows databinding is quite elaborate subject. If you want to dig deeper here are some links to keep you engaged -

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15596/BindingSource-and-BindingNavigator-in-C-2-0

[Data Binding in Visual Basic .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164106.aspx)